# What does "garn" mean?

Tags: meaning, rosemarys-baby, ira-levin

In *Rosemary's Baby*:

> She asked him questions   that    had been    unspeakable in  Catholic    High;   he sent her  to  a  night    course  in philosophy   at NYU.     “I’ll  make     a  duchess out of   this cockney    flower  girl    yet,”   he  said,   and     Rosemary    had     had     wit     enough  to  say “Garn!”.

What does the word "garn" mean?

Answer (score 6):

#### "Garn" is Cockney slang, in this context a reference to *Pygmalion* / *My Fair Lady*.

For the direct meaning of the word, you can check for example [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/garn#Etymology_2):

> From *go on*.
>
> Interjection
>
> **garn**
>
> *(Cockney slang)* A response that expresses disbelief or mockery.

The example quote provided in that Wiktionary page is from George Bernard Shaw's play [*Pygmalion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygmalion_(play)), which was adapted into a [famous musical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Fair_Lady) and later an [award-winning film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Fair_Lady_(film)) both titled *My Fair Lady*. The story is about a linguistic professor who teaches a Cockney flower girl to speak "proper" English in order to pass her off as a duchess - the passage you quote from *Rosemary's Baby* is a direct and clear reference to this. Quoting from the [play *Pygmalion* itself](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/3825/3825-h/3825-h.htm) (emphasis mine):

> THE FLOWER GIRL [tickled by the performance, and laughing in spite of herself] **Garn!**
>
> THE NOTE TAKER. You see this creature with **her kerbstone English: the English that will keep her in the gutter to the end of her days. Well, sir, in three months I could pass that girl off as a duchess** at an ambassador's garden party. I could even get her a place as lady's maid or shop assistant, which requires better English. That's the sort of thing I do for commercial millionaires. And on the profits of it I do genuine scientific work in phonetics, and a little as a poet on Miltonic lines.

You can also [listen to the line "Garn" from the film adaptation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRTcpsoM00Q), and [read more about its meaning from our friends at the English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/167920/87724).

In the passage you quote from *Rosemary's Baby*, it seems that Hutch is trying to raise Rosemary's intellectual and social level - responding to "improper" question by sending her to philosophy classes. He likens himself to Henry Higgins, the linguist who trains flower seller Eliza Doolittle to speak like a duchess. Rosemary has wit enough to reply in kind, saying "Garn!" in Eliza Doolittle style.

Comment: Dammit, that "garn" clip on Youtube is weirdly compelling. I now want a 10-hour version of that on repeat :-P

Comment: It's no longer available ... it's *garn*.